# Equivalent substrcount(PHP) in android java

Tags: android, substr

I need to know the count of a character in a String Variable. It's possible in PHP with `substrcount`.

Now, what's Equivalent `substrcount` in android(java)?

Edited :

For example count of (`:`) in

```
  String a="abc:def:gh:test"
```

---------> count of (`:`) = 3

Comment: Do you mean how many characters in a string. you want to count it ?

Comment: no - i edit ask , plz see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes StringTokenizer is there, You can try following way,

```
String str = "abc:def:gh:test";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,":");
int count = st.countTokens() - 1;
```